# "Do diving" wrong, informal ?

Tags: grammar

I am doing CAE in Buenos Aires in my mock exam I said "I do diving". My teacher didin't like it at all. However, I found it widely used. Is it a wrong use of English or very informal ?

Thanks in advance
Alejandro Mandl

Comment: Related: [Playing sports - does swimming count?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/392338/playing-sports-does-swimming-count)

Comment: It's more idiomatic to say "I dive".

Comment: Please indicate your research.

Comment: @DanBron Or, "I **go** diving"?

Comment: Hello, thanks everyody. Ok, it is better to say, I dive, I go dive, but I do diving is acceptable among friends or definitely wrong ?

Comment: How was the CAE question worded? (Context can make a big difference.)

Comment: Alejandro, it's informal  and  [hackneyed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/hackneyed). If you're saying it to be cool,   you're failing. Just say *I go diving*,  *I dive*, *One of my interests/pastimes is diving*, *I like to dive*, *Diving is a hobby of mine*, *I love to go diving*.....

Comment: I got it, thank you very much to all of you. Lawrence, I appreciate your question but I guess it is enough. I won´t say I do diving anymore. Have a wonderful day !

Comment: Don't write "I do diving" in a CAE (Advanced) *exam*, but by all means you can say it. See Clare's suggestions which are all idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to say, 'I dive'. You don't need to add 'do' before verbs. The only time it's really necessary to add 'do' is if you are emphasising the verb, e.g. someone says, 'You don't dive' and you want to correct them, 'I do dive', or if the activity is a noun, e.g. 'I do paintings' (although, 'I paint paintings' would be preferable).